# How to insert escape characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to insert all escape characters in a column in MySQL. I can not insert \ always because a long data may have a lot escape characters.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: why is a lot of escaping characters a problem.

Comment: if i inert the belong string eg = i am ' a "soft \ware engineer

then there is a problem because of escape characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am getting this correct but you

- have a lot of data
- you want to insert them into database with regular SQL commands
- most of data requires escaping.

So you have no much options. Since there is no `direct binary mode` in MySQL you

- either execute SQL script with escaping
- you will write parametrized queries and insert data directly with some custom tool you will write.

If choosing first approach have a look at [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html) for some escaping string details. Particularly you may escape one backslash `\` with double backslashes `\\` sequence. Also have a look at [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes), which eliminates need for escaping completly.

Comment: NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES doesn't eliminate the need for escaping, it only makes MySQL compliant with the ANSI SQL string literal syntax, where `"` is the only character to need escaping, and it is escaped by doubling to `""`.